# Write failure and success apex test class to check permission set group status

Tags: unit-test

I am trying to prevent certain parts of code in a method not to run if the permission set groups are updating in the background. I want to test on both conditions which are the psg Status in 'Updating' mode and psg Status in 'Updated' mode. On the test method I wrote below I am not sure how to test both conditions.

I have this method below on which the code inside the if condition should only run if none of the permission set groups are updating.

```
private class testClass {
   public static boolean testPSGStatus() {
        Boolean permissionSetGroupInUpdatingMode = false;

        for (PermissionSetGroup psg: [SELECT Id, Status FROM PermissionSetGroup]) {
            if (psg.Status != 'Updated') {
                permissionSetGroupInUpdatingMode = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!permissionSetGroupInUpdatingMode) {
                //run this section if the permission set groups are not updating
           return false;
        }
        return true;
  }
}
```

This is the test method I wrote to test the above method -

```
@IsTest
    static void testAboveMethod() {
        Boolean psgStatus;
        PermissionSetGroup psg1 = new PermissionSetGroup(DeveloperName='testPSG1', 
        MasterLabel='testPSG1');

        insert new PermissionSetGroup[] { psg1 };

        Test.calculatePermissionSetGroup(new Id[] { psg1.Id });

        List<PermissionSetGroup> psg = [SELECT Id, Status from PermissionSetGroup WHERE 
        DeveloperName='testPSG1' LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('PSG Status -'+psg.Status); This says 'Updated' always. How do I force value 'Updating' and test otherwise?
        
        Test.startTest();
        psgStatus = testClass.testPSGStatus();
        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertEquals(true, psgStatus);
}
```

---

UPDATED as per David Reeds answer -

@David Reed -This is what I am understanding - the permission set group query call inside the testPSGStatus method needs to be moved to a method like below -

```
 **public with sharing class testClass {
    private static Boolean permissionSetGroupInUpdatedMode;

    @TestVisible
    private static void setPermissionSetGroupUpdateStatus(Boolean value) {
        permissionSetGroupInUpdatedMode = value;
    }

    //Query call pulled outside of the actual method being tested. 
    public static Boolean checkPermissionSetGroupsStatus() {
        permissionSetGroupInUpdatedMode = true;
        for (PermissionSetGroup psg: [SELECT Id, Status FROM PermissionSetGroup]) {
            if (psg.Status != 'Updated') {
                permissionSetGroupInUpdatedMode = false;
                break;
            } 
        }
        return permissionSetGroupInUpdatedMode;
    }

    public static boolean methodToTest() {
        permissionSetGroupInUpdatedMode = false
        checkPermissionSetGroupsStatus();//I am guessing this method call wont have any effect on test results as it is not testVisible
               
        if (permissionSetGroupInUpdatedMode) {  
            return true;
        }
        return permissionSetGroupInUpdatedMode;       
            
    }
}
```

-------------------------------TEST CLASS-----------------------------------

```
 @IsTest
    private class testAboveClassMethod {
        @IsTest
        static void testSuccess_IfPermissionSetGroupsAreUpdated() {
       
            Boolean result;
            testClass.setPermissionSetGroupUpdateStatus(TRUE);
            
            Boolean expectedResult = true;
            Test.startTest();        
            result = testClass.methodToTest();
            Test.stopTest();
    
            System.assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
    
        }
    
        @IsTest
        static void testFailed_IfPermissionSetGroupsAreUpdating() {
       
            Boolean result;
            testClass.setPermissionSetGroupUpdateStatus(FALSE);
            
            Boolean expectedResult = false;
            Test.startTest();        
            result = testClass.methodToTest();
            Test.stopTest();
    
            System.assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
    
        }
    }**
```

Comment: This debug statement inside the testAboveMethod test class System.debug('PSG Status -'+psg.Status); says 'Updated' always. How do I force value 'Updating' and test otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You'll have to address this testing objective with dependency injection: modifying your code to segregate the PermissionSetGroup query into a separate code unit, and, under testing, replace that code unit with a new one that returns hard-coded data.

You have no ability to control the `PermissionSetGroup` updating process.

This is typical of most processes where you wish to query or interact with metadata that is outside your control.

Comment: Hello David, I have added an update to the original post. I have added revised the whole code as per my understanding of what you put in as an answer. Please advise if I am in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, I think something like that is the right approach.

Comment: Thanks @David Reed